# Sync gem not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I've got a sync partial that is under `sync/booths/_chat_widget.html.haml`
Chats controller and Booths controller.

I have below code that is under `booths/show.html.haml`

```
= sync partial: 'chat_widget', resource: @booth
```

Which is:

```
#chat_widget{:title => "Booth chat", :style => "display:none;"}
  .panel
    .panel-body
      %ul.chat
        - @booth.chats.each do |chat|
          = render partial: "chats/chat", locals: { chat: chat }
    .panel-footer
      = simple_form_for(@booth, url: chats_path, method: :post, remote: true) do |f|
        .input-group
          %input#chat-message.form-control.input-sm{name: "chat[message]", placeholder: "Type your message here...", type: "text"}
          %input{type: "hidden", name: "chat[from_user_id]", value: "#{current_user.id}"}
          %input{type: "hidden", name: "chat[chattable_id]", value: "#{@booth.id}"}
          %input{type: "hidden", name: "chat[chattable_type]", value: "Booth"}
          %span.input-group-btn
            %button#btn-chat.btn.btn-warning.btn-sm{:type => 'submit'}
              Send
        = f.error_notification
```

This creates the Chats in Chats controller with below code:

```
def create
    @chat = Chat.new(chat_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @chat.save
        sync_update @chat
        format.html{ redirect_to @chat, notice: 'Chat was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html{ render action: 'new' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

However this does not seem to update at all. Is this because it should be under `sync/chat` folder since the main show view is under Booth?

Comment: why do you said `gem`?

Comment: @majioa it's using sync gem

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Are you find this issue ? because I am also facing the same problem, could you please help me if you resolve this issue.